# Custom notification event in Gravity forms is not attaching PDF

Tags: wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

I am using Gravity forms with PDF extension. 
I have User notification with event "Form is submitted". In this case, everything works fine, email comes and attachment is there.

But I have created custom event for "User notification" like so:

```
add_filter( 'gform_notification_events', function( $events ) {

    $events['custom_status'] = __( 'Custom status' );
    return $events;

} );
```

But now, email comes, but **WITHOUT** attachment. Do I have to programmatically tell Gravity forms to attach PDF also on custom events ?